# How to define exact part of screen that is visible + scrolling animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm new to this sort of things and I do have a couple issues.
Hope you can point me in the right direction because I have lost a lot of hair over this already... :-)

URL:
[Click here](http://www.flapdopproducties.be/TESTING/test.html)

My issues:
1)How to define exact "view" (part of the screen - the TV screen to be specific) so that eg. animations will be visible only in that part of the screen?
For example the link should only be visible from a specific position to a specific position
I *think* that would solve the issues I have with premature execution of animation.
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

I have implemented superscrollorama for the scrolling animations.

2)When reverse scrolling it doesn't do anything even while the "reverse" property is explicitly set to true. Why?

3)In Firefox everything seems to be working OK, but in Chrome it looks like the animation is done even before the div comes into view. Why? How can I fix this?
Same in IE...

4)I want to spin a div with id "spin-it" into the first/left golden frame, how can I specify the exact right scroll position so it will scroll from & to the exact right position?

Maybe these animations should better be done without using Superscrollorama?

It could also be handy to know my screen resolution is 1366*768. I'm planning to fix/check other resolutions once everything is up & running.

Thanks in advance!!
Kind regards

EDIT:
test.html

```
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#film').show(3000);
        //Superscroll
        var controller = $.superscrollorama({
            triggerAtCenter: false,
            playoutAnimations: true,
            reverse: true,
        });

        if($("#film:visible")){
        controller.addTween('#fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fade-it'), 5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
        controller.addTween('#fly-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fly-it'), 10, {css:{left:'500px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));    
        controller.addTween('#spin-it', TweenMax.from( $('#spin-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, rotation: 720}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
        }
    });
    </script>

    <div class="container"></div>

    <div class="content" style="background-color:#000000">
    <img id="film" src="img/totaalaf_klein.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="link1" id="fade-it">
        <a href = "http://www.google.be">TEST LINK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="wieFlp" id="fly-it">
        <div class="textkader" >
            <p class="bigtext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="test" id="spin-it">
        <img src="img/testing.png"/>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

For some reason the  code does not display but in there it's refs to JQuery plugins and Superscrollorama and the like.

Style.css

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }


    body {font-family: sans-serif;}




    #film{
        display:none;
    }

    .content {
        border: 2px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 130px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        background-color: #000000;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 900px;
        /*height: 596px;*/height: 3000px;
    }

    .link1{
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 45%;
        padding-left: 20%;
        z-index: 4;
    }   

    .container{
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: url('../img/bgtest2.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .down {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 4;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .textkader{
        width: 200px;
        background: url('../img/classy_fabric.png');
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
        text-shadow: 
            1px 1px 0 transparent,
            2px 2px 0 #101010;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .bigtext{
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .wieFlp{
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 110%;
        //padding-left: 18.5%;
        right: 867px;
        /*z-index: 2;*/
        z-index:2;
    }
```

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: Are you using doc ready or window load? Chrome appies 0 dimensions to images before window load which can mess up any code working out heights if it's in a doc ready.

Comment: I thought the URL was sufficient but I'll add some in my original post.
Thank you for viewing this question!   

@Coop, I'm using doc ready

Comment: Try taking your code for calling scrollorama out of the doc ready and put it in $(window).load instead. That might solve the issue with Chrome

Comment: Thanks Coop!Well that didn't work... But I keep trying to find a solution.